# if then do multiple statements from SAS to R

Tags: r, if-statement, sas

I am new to R. Here is the SAS script that I want to replicate in R:

```
if a=4 or b=4 then do;
  if a=1 or b=1 then news="AB";
  else if a=2 or b=2 then news="BC";
  else news="CD";
  end;
else do;
  if a=1 or b=1 then news="DF";
  else news="GH";
end;
```

Where: a, b are variables (columns's name) of the table/data, and news is a new variable that I want to create.

I cannot find a way of ifelse or other methods to do that in R. Can you help me? Thank you!

Here is my first try on first part of the above script:

```
news <- ifelse(a==4 | b==4,
           ifelse(a==1 | b==1, "AB",
              ifelse(a==2 | b==2, "BC", "CD")))
```

But it did not work. The error shows 
    "Error in ifelse(a == 4 | b == 4, ifelse(a == 1 | b ==  : 
      argument "no" is missing, with no default"

Do you know why? Also, I am not sure how to link the second part, starting from "else do" to R. I feel like SAS script is easier to understand and write in this case than R.

Comment: what methods/functions/operators have you explored so far?

Comment: ifelse() in R is not a difficult skill to conquer. Try it ...very easy!

Comment: Please see my updates on the original post. Thank you!

Comment: What does "*did not work*" mean? What are `a` and `b`? I set `a <- 4` and `b <- 2` and ran your code, ended up with `news` as `"BC"`, which looks correct.

Comment: To exactly duplicate the SAS code, I think all you need to do is add `, ifelse(a == 1 | b == 1, "DF", "GH")` before the last parenthesis.

Comment: @Gregor, post as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ifelse` is appropriate for vectors (i.e., you must test a vector and the output must be a vector of the same length as the input), `if() {...} else {...}` is  for single conditions. Without sample input (and not really knowing SAS), I'm not sure which you're after. If `a` and `b` are single values, R Schifini's answer is good.

If `a` and `b` are vectors, then you are right to use `ifelse`, and your code works just fine for me. We can extend it to include the last `else do` statement:

```
test = expand.grid(a = c(1, 2, 4, 7), b = c(1, 2, 4))
a = test$a
b = test$b
news <- ifelse(a == 4 | b == 4,
               ifelse(a == 1 | b == 1, "AB",
                      ifelse(a == 2 | b == 2, "BC", "CD")),
               ifelse(a == 1 | b == 1, "DF", "GH"))

cbind(test, news)
#    a b news
# 1  1 1   DF
# 2  2 1   DF
# 3  4 1   AB
# 4  7 1   DF
# 5  1 2   DF
# 6  2 2   GH
# 7  4 2   BC
# 8  7 2   GH
# 9  1 4   AB
# 10 2 4   BC
# 11 4 4   CD
# 12 7 4   CD
```

Comment: I added the second part of R script like you suggested and it worked fine. Thank you for the correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

This is a direct translation. I am not simplifying the logic.

Conditions are placed in `()`, `or` => `||`, and equality test: `==`.

```
if(a==4 || b==4){
  if (a==1 || b==1) {
    news="AB"
  } else if (a==2 || b==2){
    news="BC"
  } else {
    news="CD"
  }
} else {
  if (a==1 || b==1){
    news="DF"
  } else {
    news="GH"
  }
}
```

If you want to use `ifelse()` you will end up with several nested conditions that are usually hard to read.

Comment: it might be slightly better practice to use `||` rather than `|` for tests of scalar conditions ...

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Schifini!